# partition discovery not working for spark avro reader

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read the AVRO files which are partitioned by year, month and date. For example:

**Complete file path**

```
/test/data/source1/year=2018/month=2/day=14/file.avro
```

**Base path**

```
/test/data/source1/
```

**Sample code**

```
val df = sqlContext
                .read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.avro")
                .option("basePath", "/test/data/source1/")
                .option("avroSchema", avroSchema.toString())
                .load("/test/data/source1/year=2018/")
```

In the output DF, the `year` column is not shown up. What could be the issue?

As per the Spark documentation [Partition Discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery), it should work.

**Update:**

I'm using Spark 1.6, for AVRO its not working, but for Parquet its working..

Comment: As far as I interpret the referenced documentation, the `.load` path should be `/test/data/source1/` too if you like to have a column with `year`. Can you give it a try?

Comment: @U880D: No, the reason we are giving load path with year partition column is we need to read the data only for the data, even though if the base path contains the data for multiple years.

Comment: I am no certain, but, it seems that partition discovery only works on parquet.